# Number format for accounts

Tags: formatting

I am using `spreadtab` to prepare financial statements for presentation. However, I wish to present negative numbers in brackets (parentheses) within the table:
`-3,210` as (3,210)

I don't even know if this is possible. I am a total beginner as far as LaTeX is concerned, so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: It would be helpful to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.  That way those trying to help can focus on solution as opposed to setting up the problem test case which may not match how you are using it.

Answer (score 8):

An example of your input might be useful for giving better advice, but this code in the preamble seems to do what you need:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\FPifneg{#1}(\@gobble#1)\else#1\fi}
\makeatother
```

The `\@gobble` macro swallows the minus sign, whose presence is tested with `\FPifneg` (section 3.2 in the manual of `spreadtab`).